# Trying to order DD-MM with sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I  have birthdays stored as DD-MM, I did not think about sorting them but now I am trying to sort them anyway, could this be done? I tried:

```
const bdays = db.prepare('SELECT id, server, substr(datum, 1, 2) || "-" || substr(datum, 4, 5) as date FROM birthdays WHERE server = ? ORDER BY date').all(message.guild.id);
let people = '';
for (const data of bdays) {
    people += `**${client.users.get(data.id).username}** - ${data.datum}\n`;
    message.channel.send(data.datum);
}
```

But it gives me `SqliteError: near "substr": syntax error`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from your table?

Comment: I have 3 columns: id, server and datum, datum has birthdays in DD-MM format like 20-11 or 30-08

Comment: If you change your format to `MM-DD` you can just ORDER BY that column directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because SQLite didn't support `to_date` function.

You can try to use `substr` and multiple `order by`

**Schema (SQLite v3.18)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    col VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('02-28');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('03-05');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('01-01');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  col,substr(col,1,2),substr(col,4,2)
FROM T
ORDER BY substr(col,1,2),substr(col,4,2);

| col   | substr(col,1,2) | substr(col,4,2) |
| ----- | --------------- | --------------- |
| 01-01 | 01              | 01              |
| 02-28 | 02              | 28              |
| 03-05 | 03              | 05              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mZeZsXZMNXj5sUDyYPaLz/3)